# Building a Java Application

Tags: java, jar, build, build-process, executable-jar

I am a newbie interested in becoming a software engineer. I recently applied to an entry level position and was asked to do a coding assignment. This is why I am asking this question.

The feedback I got was that I should learn to use Java deployment tools so that  other developers with built jars can to run my code, rather than just sending the raw code.

My question is assuming I have a simple java program HelloWorld.java and want to send this code to someone, what is an example of a java deployment tool (And steps to use it) to use so I can provide other developers with built jars to run the code, rather than just sending the raw code.

Thanks in advance for any feedback

Comment: If you have one file of HelloWorld.java - simply send it "as is". It's only when you have a project that includes multiple files/directories - when you have to package it into a jar/war.

Comment: Perhaps they were suggesting you write a maven `pom` file. Unfortunately, this is a guess because your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried to get a more detailed feed back but that was all I was given. What I did was I just sent them the file as it is. So that is required is compile and run it from the terminal

Comment: too broad a Q. You need some training/class on Java. One answer isn't gonna help.

Comment: @KwekuBlue You're doing well to ask such questions.  A good software engineer doesn't just write code, he also has to think about how the code is used and deployed.  JAR files cover (some) of the deployment scenarios and some of the "use" scenarios too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on the JAR file format and how to pack JARs.  Pay close attention on how to make your JARs runnable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Making a JAR runnable is detailed in "Working with Manifest Files: The Basics" / "Setting an Application's Entry Point".  Really, read the entire site on JAR files.  You will probably never read it twice, but if you at least read it once you'll have a strong grasp on what you can (and can't do) in the packaging and distribution of your code.

For example, I still encounter people who don't know that JARs can be sealed, have various tamper-proofing capabilities, can contain class-paths, can embed version numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The java self-contained tool **`jar`** maybe a good choice.

1. prepare the `class` file and `manifest` file
2. enter the console with command `cmd` and ensure all the class files in the current directory
3. run `jar cmf yourManifestFile yourFile.jar *.class`

More help for `jar` command, forwads

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

More help for `manifest` file format, forwards

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest